# arrayToList producing odd outputs. What's wrong?

Tags: javascript, arrays, list, data-structures, linked-list

I was doing this exercise on a book, and it asks to write a function that converts arrays to lists (an object with properties of "value", which stores the value, and "rest", which points to the next value).

Here is the solution given by the book:

```
    function arrayToList(array) {
      var list = null;
      for (var i = array.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        list = {value: array[i], rest: list};
      return list;
    }

    console.log(arrayToList([10, 20, 30]));
// → {value: 10, rest: {value: 20, rest: {value: 30, rest: null}}}
```

and here's the solution I came up with:

```
function arrayToList(array){
  var list = {value: null, rest: null};
  var tempList={value: array[array.length-1], rest: null};
  for(var i=array.length-2; i>=0;i--){
     list.value = array[i];
     list.rest = tempList;
     tempList = list;
  }
  return list;
};
console.log(arrayToList([10, 20, 30]));
```

But this produces a result that looks like this:

```
{value: 10, rest: {value: 10, rest: {value: 10, …}}}
```

It works with an array of 2 elements and anything above that, this loop of 10s occurs. I have tried to dissect the code to see where exactly this happens... it seems to be where list is assigned to tempList.

Can anyone explain to me what's wrong?

Comment: Why are you calling array.length-2 within the for loop? It should be array.length-1 like the example.

Comment: Lloyd Nicholson, I did that because I already did the array.length-1 element outside the loop. to set it to the "rest" value of the array.length-2 element when the loop starts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript objects are, essentially, call by reference.  So when you are setting tempList to list, you are simply creating a *pointer*, not a copy, and therefore the second time through the loop, you set list.rest to point back to itself, thus creating an infinite rest-> {10, rest -> {10, rest -> 10 .....  what you want to do is "point" list to a *new* object, like in the book's solution.